# Why can't I insert an element and skip an index in a Vector?

Tags: java, vector, indexing

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Vector <Integer> v = new <Integer> Vector();
    v.add(1);
    v.add(2);
    v.add(3,3); // this doesn't work

    int x = v.elementAt(3);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

The above v.add(3,3) produces an error, I would like to append elements in index 0, 1 and skip to 3, but why does it produce an error? Is it not allowed in Vector?

Thank you

Comment: Please don't use `Vector`s if you don't have to. From the Javadoc of `Vector`: __If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector.__

Comment: I'm learning Java so I have to try it out.

Comment: @Ken Not really. `Vector` is an ancient class and you can just forget about it and use `ArrayList`. If you're learning Java you especially **shouldn't** do anything with `Vector`. You don't want to learn things that nobody uses anymore, do you?

Comment: @Kayaman I agree with you but if this is part of a homework-assignment which says "use vector" then he doesn't have a choice

Comment: Yes indeed, I have to learn Vector because of school. I apologize for any inconvenience caused. I will check out ArrayList as well! Thank you guys :)

Comment: I'd hate to see what else is outdated in the teaching besides this. Not that it really makes a difference if you're learning the basics of objects and such, but there's generics involved and Vector was outdated years before they came out.

Answer (score 1):

Correct: adding at a specific index is not allowed if you are trying to add past the end of the array.  See [the documentation for add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add(int,%20E)).  You first need to call [setSize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#setSize(int)) to make space.

```
v.setSize(4);
v.add(3,3)
```

should work.

Comment: why doesn't `Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<Integer>(4);` work?

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. So I would only use add() on a specific index if I were to remove something from that specific index and would like to add something back? (Assuming the Vector is filled with elements)

Comment: @Ken the method `add` doesn't remove the element from that specific index. It shifts the element and all subsequent to the right

Comment: @ParkerHalo Hi, I understand that that is for add(). The api mentioned: add(int index, E element)
Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this Vector. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add-int-E- So does that mean I can use add(int index, E element) to add something in the middle like at index 3? For example index 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 are filled.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern I use when I need to be able to skip elements is

```
final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

public void set(int index, Integer value) {
   while (list.size() <= index) list.add(null);
   list.set(index, value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, would just like to clarify some things about Vector because I'm learning Java.

Comment: @Ken `Vector` is an older form of a List which replaced it in 1998 which in computers term is ancient ;)